# How do I selectively delete nodes in a subtree of a DOM Document?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, domdocument

I am using DOMDocument to parse an html document and get some data out of it. Following is the structure of sub-tree of DOM

```
<div id="tab1">
    <div class="some class name"></div>
    <div class="some other class name">arbitrary data and nodes</div>
    <p> lot of paragraphs to follow </p>
    <p> paragraphs </p>
    <p> paragraphs </p>
    <p> paragraphs </p>
    <p> paragraphs </p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <table />
    <table />
    <table />
    <table />
</div>
```

I do not want first two children of tab1. I am using following PHP Code

```
<?php 
$urlArray = file('sitemap.txt');
$dataSet = array();
foreach($urlArray as $url){
    $scrapedData = file_get_contents('./scraped-site/'.trim($url));
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($scrapedData);
    $domXpathDoc = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $results = '';
    $xpathArray = array(
        'info'=>'//*[@id="tabs1"]',
    );
    $set = array();
    foreach($xpathArray as $field => $xpath){
        $domNodeList = $domXpathDoc->query($xpath);
        foreach($domNodeList as $node){
            foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
                $set[] = $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );
            }
        }
    }
    $dataSet[] = $set;
}
```

The code given gives me all children how can I selectively avoid any node?

Comment: Are you just looking to delete the first two children?

Comment: @JonathonG, in the structure you see I just want to delete first two elements but this may differ in some other scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[EDIT2: I tried the answer below (I learned :) ). This is working for me:*

```
"//*[@id='tabs1'][name() != 'div']"
```

Basically it tells the xpath to ignore all elements with name 'div'. You can ignore more than one element like this:

```
"//*[@id='tabs1'][name() != 'div' and name() != 'foo']"
```

Only showing elements after the first two would work like this:

```
"//*[@id='tabs1'][position()>2]"
```

Comment: I first gave an incorrect answer which I did not remove because I had not yet found the correct one. Instead I set up a notice stating it was not a correct answer. I now found a correct answer, so I removed all incorrect lines. This should be working now :)

Comment: Haha, I've been trying for almost 30 minutes now. Thanks hoppa.

Comment: @hoppa, what if I just want to ignore only one div, and use next, divs in my case do not have any ID, am quite new to DOM and Xpath, so please bear with me if I sound stupid

Comment: @Kumar, so you only want divs, and not the first one. No other elements but divs? Or do you always want to just skip the first found element? In that case use the third code snippet and change the 2 to a 1. 

Your question states that you want to ignore the first two divs inside a div with id 'tab1'. The third code snippet should do exactly that.

Comment: @hoppa, thanks a ton! Any pointer where I can read more about this?

Comment: @Kumar I'm not a great fun of the w3schools site but they have a nice list of possibilities here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp
 There are several pages there don't forget to click trough them.